# How do I configure Gmail so "Remove Formatting" reverts to the settings specified in "Default Text Style"?

Tags: gmail

In Gmail, I have Verdana specified in the "Default Text Style" setting. When I click *remove  formatting*, it reverts to Sans Serif. What I'd like it to do is just remove the bold or font-size that came with pasted text. Is there a way to configure Gmail so that remove formatting to revert the selected text to Verdana normal with normal size?

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 personal Gmail accounts and also one account for my work, where we use Google Apps.

Surprisingly, in my 2 personal accounts, the behaviour is what you want - i.e., when clicking *remove formatting*, it falls back to your default settings, including any changes you made in your default settings.

In my work email, however, I have the same problem you are describing.

So I guess it depends on some configuration of the version of Google Apps my company is using. I am afraid that is not something you can configure *inside* your Gmail account.

Comment: My account is a standard standalone gmail account and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

After further testing, I observed that the font face will be set to the default if I use FireFox 38.0.5, but Sans-Serif if I use Safari 8.0.6 or MailPlane 3.5.0.

Comment: Safari 9.0 also resets to Sans-Serif